# Load Excel into cube SSAS

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, cube, olap-cube

I have a cube in SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) and I would like to be able to load the data that I have in an Excel file in the cube, is it possible to connect it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a data source :
[image]

Create a database based on a new connection :

[image]

Choose the right provider `ACE 14 OLE DB provider`, you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/data-sources-supported-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15) to have an idea on data providers :

[image]